# Yii2 required validation rule on "select2" widget

Tags: php, validation, yii2, jquery-select2, kartik-v

I'm using [kartik select2 widget](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2) in Yii2 framework. Required validation rule doesn't work on it. 
Here is my view code:

```
$form->field($model, 'city')->widget(\kartik\select2\Select2::classname(), [
            'data' => $cities,
            'options' => [
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'placeholder' => 'Please select city...',
                'multiple' => false,
            ],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowClear' => true
            ],
        ])->label('City');
```

Here is my model rule code:

```
[['city'], 'required'],
[['city'], 'integer']
```

Any idea to make the dropdown required?

Comment: The code looks fine. What happens? Does it store empty values?

Comment: From what we got, it is not sufficient. You may need to provide more code (model, controller action).

Comment: @ali-tavafi did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in plugin option

```
pluginOptions' => [                   
                'initialize' => true,
            ],
```

This is working code for me

```
 $form->field($model, 'tech_type')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
            'options'=>['id'=>'tech-id'],
            'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Techtypes::find()->asArray()->all(), 'tech_id', 'tech_type'),
            'pluginOptions'=>[
                'initialize' => true,
                'placeholder' => 'Select Technician Type ...',
            ]
        ]);
```